# Is this single Collatz rule useful?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, collatz-conjecture

I have thought of a single simple rule for Colatz conjecture that is slightly different to the normal one. Here it is:

$$f:(a,b)\rightarrow (3a+\gcd(a,b),b)$$

Then the Colatz conjecture can be written as:

$$\forall_{n:\mathbb{N}}\exists_{m:\mathbb{N}}\exists_{p:\mathbb{N}}\{ f^p(n,2^m) = (2^m,2^m)\}$$

**Examples:**

the orbit $5\rightarrow 16\rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1$ is written:
$$(5,16) \rightarrow (16,16)$$
The orbit $17,52,26,13,20,10,5,16,8,4,2,1$ becomes:
$$(17,512)\rightarrow (52,512) \rightarrow (160,512) \rightarrow (512,512)$$

Is this known? And is this an improvement or just makes things worse?

Comment: "is this an improvement?" Unless someone can use it to prove the conjecture (which I doubt), it's probably not

Comment: I don't really see how this improves, it simply seems to remove the "divide by 2" step.

Comment: Yeah probably isn't useful! But I think it's quite nice.